# Laravel 5.8 Eloquent doesn't work as intended despite the raw dumped query from it works

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm having an issue with Eloquent querying things different than if I'm using the raw query, despite it returning the exact same raw query when I dump it with `toSql()`

This should return 3 rows, but instead returns 40

```
$equipment = Equipment::where(["class_id" => $this->classId, "class_id2" => $this->classId, "class_id3" => $this->classId])
                    ->orWhere(["class_id" => 0, "class_id2" => 0, "class_id3" => 0])
                    ->where("type_id", ">", "7")
                    ->get();
```

This returns 3 and works as expected

```
$equipment = \DB::table("equipment")
                        ->whereRaw("(`class_id` = ".$this->classId." and `class_id2` = ".$this->classId." and `class_id3` = ".$this->classId.") 
                                    or (`class_id` = ".$this->classId." or `class_id2` = ".$this->classId." or `class_id3` = ".$this->classId.") 
                                    and `type_id` > 7")
                        ->get();
```

The exact raw query Eloquent dumps is this:

```
select * 
from `equipment` 
where (`class_id` = 14 and `class_id2` = 14 and `class_id3` = 14) 
   or (`class_id` = 14 or `class_id2` = 14 or `class_id3` = 14) 
  and `type_id` > 7
```

When running this in Navicat, it also returns 3 rows.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be more explicit about your groups of conditions, which you can do by using an anonymous function as the argument to the first `where()`, with the argument of `$query` (which will be the querybuilder object itself).

```
$classID = 14;
$equipment = Equipment::where(function($query) use ($classID) {
                                  $query->where('class_id', $classID)
                                        ->orWhere('class_id2', $classID)
                                        ->orWhere('class_id3', $classID);
                        })->where("type_id", ">", "7")
                        ->get();
```

The query you currently have doesn't make that much sense, as the `OR` conditions will always be true when the `AND` condition is, so we can remove the first part of it, thereby simplifying the query.

You can debug your queries by using `toSql()` instead of `get()`, which will print the final SQL string. Had you done that here, you'd see that the conditions becomes something like `WHERE .. OR .. AND ..`, instead of `WHERE (.. OR ..) AND ..`.

Comment: I did debug my query with `toSql()`, but your function seem to give `syntax error, unexpected '}'`

Comment: Forgot a colon at the end of `orWhere()`, that should be fixed now.

Comment: For some reason it's still not returning the correct rows. I'm still looking at about 40 rows instead of 3...

Comment: Alright, let's take a step back here. Can you create a DB Fiddle (for example at http://sqlfiddle.com), with the data you have - and which rows you expect to get back? My guess is that the `orWhere()` part will trigger on 37 more rows than intended, but without seeing the actual data and which rows you expect, its hard to say.

Comment: Alright, so how do you get the class ID of 14? We can also simplify the query quite a bit.

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ',' or ')'` is what I get now. You missed the `->` which I added but it returns the same error anyway. Edit: After your fix this finally works. Thank you so much!